# npm package to select cities, on the basis of country?

Tags: angular, npm

I have a angular project, where i want to use a npm package to select cities or state on the basis of country whichever, i select from UI. is there any pacakage available or any api?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-places-autocomplete

Comment: No actually google places autocomplete doesn't provide the whole state or city list of selected country, i want if a user select "India" from dropdown, so, he/she will get the whole state or city list of india.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/w_UXnmewpXk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=YOUR_USERNAME&country=in&orderby=population&maxRows=100&style=SHORT

this api helps me to find states or city on the basis of country code.

rest documentation you can find [here](http://www.geonames.org)

for install using npm

> npm install --save geonames.js

npm readme [geonames](https://github.com/kinotto/geonames.js)